# Action Script Convert Function to an Object

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, prototype

I need to convert a function to an object. For example, when I need to use the variable called `fn` I want to be able to use it as a function `fn()` or as an object `fn.json()`. I have code to do it, but I think it's not correct.

```
package lib.smartic {
// import
import lib.smartic.smartic;
// constructor $
public var fn = function(s):smartic{
    return new smartic(s);
};
Function.prototype.json = function (s) {
    // call
};}
```

How can I apply the prototype to my variable `fn`, not just to the object class?

Comment: Prototyping is a bad pattern to implement if you have full control of the source code I would not recommend you do it. With that being said I think you also need to read up on what exactly prototyping does, I get the feeling you do not have a full grasp on it.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do it without using prototype ?

Comment: AS3 is an object oriented language - use it as such.

Comment: @AhmedSaber I could give you an example but the code you posted just does not make sense to me so I can not use that as a base. What you could do however is to read up on class inheritance.

Comment: All I get from your comments and code is that you want to have a function stored in a variable so you can call the function by the variable name. Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Function is an Object... and as said @The_asMan, you shouldn't use prototypes.

Simple example:

```
var smartic: Smartic = new Smartic("someValue");
trace(smartic.json());
```

And definition of your Smartic class, without prototypes:

```
public class Smartic {
    private var _value:String;

    public function Smartic(value:String) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public function json():String {
        return "Some json here";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there is away to call smartic object as Function smartic(value) ?

Comment: No. If you work with Functions, pass method, and work with it as you want. `smartic.func(value);` or `someReceiver.doSomething(smartic.func)`;

Comment: AS is OOP, it's not like JS. The way to do it here is static methods - they can be called without instantiating a class.

But anyways I still can't understand why exactly you want this to be BOTH a function and an object (class) that has functions inside it? What's the point and what's the benefit? If it's not to instantiate something - go with statics..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do exactily but if you want smartic to be a function you can do something like this:

keep the code givent by Nicolas Siver and add this function:

```
public function smarticFunc(value:String):Smartic
{
    return new Smartic(value);
}
```

so you can use smarticFunc as function or as Smartic as it returns a Smartic.